# can i use in_array () in Shopify

Tags: shopify

I am new To Shopify ! i am trying to something like,i want to check that,the ID which i put on Textbox is in array or not !

**here is my Product.Liquid**

```
{% if settings.make_an_offer %}
    {% for id in product.id %}

    {% include 'pricewaiter' %}
    {% endfor %}

{% endif %}
```

in above code,i need to check that **settings.make_an_offer** is in this array **product.id** or not..
**make_an_offer** this is an ID of my Textbox

so how can i do this?

any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Place it like this :

```
{% for id in product.id %}
   {% if settings.make_an_offer === id %}
      {% include 'pricewaiter' %}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```